# Xcode, big array of NsDictionary consume all my RAM

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary, ram, sourcekit

i have a problem with my new app. I have to get and parse a big xml from a WebService, using **XmlToDictionary** to make all easier.
When i try to build my app, if i look in the task manager, the is a task ("SourceKit") which consumes all my RAM.
Searching on internet i think that i understood the problem : The result of my parsing is a big array of **NSDictionary** with *"not explicitly"* type.

So my question is : do you know another way to manage this array of NSDictionary ? Or a method for explicitly declare this array? or any another way? 
This is my code :

```
 //The block of the HTTP connection for get the xml form the WebService.
    operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (operation, response) -> Void in

            parser = response as? XMLParser
            let XmlPars = XmlParsing()
            XmlPars.parsing(parser: parser!)



            }, failure: { (operation, error) -> Void in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
        })
        operation.start()

    func parsing (parser : XmlParser){
    let xmlStruttureTipi = (dictionary["StruttureTipi"] as! NSDictionary)
        let struttureTipi = (xmlStruttureTipi[xmlStruttureTipi.allKeys[0]] as! Array<NSDictionary>)
        parseStruttureTipi(struttureTipi: struttureTipi)
    }

    func parseStrutture {

func parseStrutture(strutture : [NSDictionary]) {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        var ArrayStrutture = [Struttura]()
        for struttura in strutture{
            let s = Struttura()

            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let data = formatter.date(from: struttura["DataAggiornamento"] as! String)!

            if(struttura["DataAggiornamento"] != nil){s.DataAggiornamento = data}else{s.DataAggiornamento = formatter.date(from: "00-00-0000")}


            if(struttura["Longitudine"] != nil){s.Longitudine = Double((struttura["Longitudine"] as? String)!)}else{s.Longitudine = 0.0}

            if(struttura["Latitudine"] != nil){s.Latitudine = Double((struttura["Latitudine"] as? String)!)}else{s.Latitudine = 0.0}

            if(struttura["Nome"] != nil)
            {s.Nome = struttura["Nome"] as? String}
            else{s.Nome = ""}

//A lot other proprety...

            ArrayStrutture.append(s)
        }

        let repoStrutture = RepoStruture()
        repoStrutture.insertStrutture(strutture: ArrayStrutture)

    }

}
```

Comment: Look at autorelease pools if you are using more memory than expected. Use a different XML parser that doesn't parse everything in one go if that doesn't help.

Comment: I discovered that the problem is the creation of the dictionary, not the parser... but it's so strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself, the problem was the declaration od the NSDictionary : if i split it in two NSDictionary it works.
I think it's a bug of the compiler.